# How to dynamically change page title in head?

Tags: magento2

we're trying to dynamically add the SKU to the page's  tag in each product page's .

Our approach so far has been to override the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View class:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Brock\ProductTitles\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

And then in the module:

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View{

  public function _prepareLayout()
  {

      $product = $this->getProduct();
      if (!$product) {
          return parent::_prepareLayout();
      }
      $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
      $sku = $product->getSku();
      if ($title) {
        echo $title;
        echo $sku;
          $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title." - ".$sku);
      }
  }

}
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working? Or better/different ways of achieving this?

Worth nothing that when we make the above changes to the _prepareLayout function in the core file, it works, just having issues with the override.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way, you can changes the page title without rewrite the class.

Using `layout_generate_blocks_before` event, you can changes page title.

Fire an observer on this event which will change -`getBlock('page.main.title')'s` **setPageTitle** value.

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\ChangePagetitle\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverChangePagetitleForProduct implements ObserverInterface
{



    protected $_pageConfig;
    protected $_registry;   

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig  ,
     \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry   
    ) {

        $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig; 
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    if($full_action_name != 'catalog_product_view'){
    return $this;
    }
    $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product')
        if($product){
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
             $layout->getBlock('page.title')->setPageTitle($title." - ".$sku);
        }
       return $this;    
    }

}
```

Comment: This set us on the right track, thank you. We had to add calls to some IsMetaApplied methods in our code in order to get it to work for some reason, but not sure why.

Comment: Hello, I got below error while using above code. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setPageTitle() on boolean can you please help someone?

Comment: @Pribhav Same issue for me !! in Mangento 2.3

Comment: Error: Call to a member function setPageTitle() on bool, getting this error in magento-2.4

Comment: working in 2.4 with two changes. 1. event name is 'layout_generate_blocks_after' and 2. $layout->getBlock('page.main.title')

Answer (score 1):

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View{

  public function _prepareLayout()
  {

      $product = $this->getProduct();
      if (!$product) {
          return parent::_prepareLayout();
      }
      $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
      $sku = $product->getSku();
      if ($title) {
        echo $title;
        echo $sku;
          $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title." - ".$sku);
          return parent::_prepareLayout();
      }
  }
}
```

Regarless you have to call `parent::_prepareLayout();`

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by Amit is not correct. Here the correct version:

```
    <?php

namespace Devamitbera\ChangePagetitle\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use \Magento\Framework\Registry;

class ObserverChangePageTitleForProduct implements ObserverInterface
{


    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        if ($full_action_name != 'catalog_product_view') {
            return;
        }
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        if ($product) {
            $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $layout->getBlock('page.title')->setPageTitle($title . " - " . $sku);
        }
       return;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to set the same page title for all pages such app "Application Name". I tried but page goes to loading and loading.